# Sending text chat msg to other player with Game Center?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

Is it possible to send text chat msgs to other players via Game Center? is their any dedicated way to do that with the GameKit API? or would it just have to be put into the turn data that is sent between players?

Comment: You may accept one of the answers if worked...

Answer (score 2):

You have to write your own, there is no method in game center to allow for chatting.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to include small text msgs in the data that's sent in the data that's sent to game center which represents a players turn?

Comment: Right, nothing is built in, mostly you are on your own to roll your own code for this.  Helpful link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can just send the text as normal data during the game. In order to do that

Method to prepare data to send

```
-(void)sendText:(NSString *) text {

    NSString * text2Send = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text];
    [self sendData:[text2Send dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

The send data method will be the normal data sending method of Game center as

```
- (BOOL)sendDataToAllPlayers:(NSData *)data withDataMode:(GKMatchSendDataMode)mode error:(NSError **)error;
```

and in order to resolve the received data

```
NSString * rawText = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if(rawText.length > 0)
{   
    //Do what ever you want with the text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like already proposed, you can use `GKTurnBasedMatch`'s `matchData` for that. If your game is turn-based, you can have two game data message types: one for sending game data at the end of each player's turn, and the other for sending chat messages. Or you can combine them so that a message is sent when each player ends her turn. However if you only use `matchData` to send chat messages, make sure it doesn't end player's turn, otherwise you will have game synchronization issues. For that use `saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:completionHandler:` method for sending your message; on the other side GameKit will call your turn callback as it receives the message - you should read the updated `matchData` and see whether it is a message or a game state update - that's relatively easy if you use JSON or XML or NSDictionary serialization for sending data back and forth - you can introduce something like `dataType` property there that would let you distinguish between text message and game state update.

There's also an option for changing the `match.message` contents, however if you put your short message there, the opponent(s) will only see it when they receive 'your turn' notification from the GameCenter.